# Why would an Apache Server timeout on first httpd request?

Tags: wordpress, apache, timeout

I have an odd issue with my Apache Server. Almost every single time the server gets a timeout on the `httpd` first request, and then I hit reload and the page loads right up. What could possibly cause this?

I looked into the server errors, there is nothing except that `wdaemon` is not running. I looked into `top` and everything looks fine. I checked on GTmetrix and it also gets timeout on first request! And when GTmetrix returns the stats nothing looks out of the ordinary.

The httpd requests a WordPress project, using a 3rd party plugin (P3 Plugin Profiler) I analyze the active plugin response and it also looks fine, average.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo** based on the self answer by the OP - "*The problem indeed was internal, not server related. After analyzing with more caution I noticed a plugin was taking too long to load so I disabled it and it made all the difference*".

Answer (score 0):

The problem indeed was internal, not server related. After analyzing with more caution I noticed a plugin was taking too long to load so I disabled it and it made all the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Could be all sorts of things. WordPress can be a nightmare for performance - usually as a result of too many, badly written plugins. But the first place to check is your PHP opcode cache how you interest the data depends on which opcode cache you are using - APC is a very different beast from then zend cache. You didn't say which applies here, but even describing just one goes way beyond what's practical here. If you have *any* plugins, you should have listed them in your question. Try disabling them all and see if the problem persists. Then start adding them back one at a time till the problem recurs.

If you think you have sufficient understanding of the profiler to make a diagnosis why did you tell us about it? If your not an expert in profiling WordPress why didn't you include the output of the profiler in your question?